# Minimum value for Squared multiple correlations between items and factors

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

When building a CFA model, each of item that form a latent variable has its own squared multiple correlation coefficient or reability. Is there a minimum value for squared multiple correlations (R^2)? Could you please suggest some references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific minimum, although I dare say that rules of thumb have been suggested.

It also might be suggested that you want the loadings to be statistically significant (but let's not get into debates about statistical significance).

Smaller loadings mean that the reliability of each item is lower, but the composite reliability depends on the individual reliabilities and the number of items.

A second issue is what to do if your loadings don't exceed the threshold. Do you remove them? If so, you're testing a different theory and at risk of overfitting. Do you remove the loading? (Same problem, plus that variable is now potentially connected to nothing.)

Comment: one item has an R^2 of 0.2, however, the latent variable has a composite reliability of 0.9. I think composite reliability is the way to go.

Comment: 0.2 is fine. That's a loading of around 0.44.